# colors.xml not generating the correct values in gen/R file?

Tags: android, xml, colors, r.java-file

I'm trying to access each of the values in colors.xml, but the int (hex) values in the R/color class doesn't match corresponding values that are defined in colors.xml. Here are some sample values:

```
 R/color (all of which starts with 0x7f0400...):
    public static final int AliceBlue=0x7f04002d;
    public static final int AntiqueWhite=0x7f040023;
    public static final int Aqua=0x7f04007d;
    public static final int Aquamarine=0x7f040062;
    public static final int Azure=0x7f04002b;
...

 But in colors.xml (all of which starts with #00...):
    <color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
    <color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
    <color name="Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
    <color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

The values in the `R` file are not the values that you define they are the `id` that will be assigned to each `color` so you access them. You can use `R.color.AliceBlue` and it will give you the value you assigned to it in `colors.xml`. **Do Not modify the R.java file. It is generated automatically.**

Comment: When I used "R.color.Red" for example, the color is not outputted a red color, and this has been the same for other colors defined in colors.xml as well. I've double checked the values of colors.xml and they are correct. Heres how I'm using it to color certain characters of my Spannable string: "spnStr",  spnStr.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.Red), i, i+1, android.text.Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: @jerryh91 see my updated answer on how to reference the color

Answer (score 1):

The number in your `R.java` (`0x7f04002d`) isn't suppose to correspond to your hex code in `colors.xml` (ex. `F0F8FF`). The `int` number in `R.java` is an identifier that the system generates when you compile your program.

When you access it with `R.color.AliceBlue` it will reference the `int` in `R.java` and should return the correct color.

You shouldn't even need/want to be messing around in `R.java` so don't worry about what's in there as long as it is returning the correct colors. Also note that you can't rely on that `int` because they can change from compile to compile so you don't want to reference that `int`. You just reference the name you gave it to refer to such as `AntiqueWhite`.

To reference this you need to get a `Color` by referencing its `id` using `getColor()`

```
new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(AliceBlue));
```