# how to get background color of textview in robotium

Tags: java, android, css, junit, robotium

Hi guys i m trying to get the background color of the TextView but unable to find it.

I am doing sanity automation testing of my chat app using robotium.

Main objective is to find weather textview bubble color is grey or blue and put assertion.

```
    ArrayList<TextView> textViewList = solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class);

    for (TextView textview : textViewList )
    {
        if (textview != null && textview.isShown()) 
        {
            if(textview.getText().toString().equals(Message))
            {
                ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable)textview.getBackground();
                int color= drawable.getColor();
                //doing some assertion 

            }
        }
    }
```

this is what i m trying to get color but having expception

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to
    android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
```

kindly help me with this thanks :)

Comment: why dont you use two text messages (sent and received) and assert for them

Answer (score 1):

after some research you can get the text color from a text view using

```
TextView text = (TextView) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.TextViewColor);
text.getCurrentTextColor();
```

the problem is that the text color returned is the one from R.java not the one used in your xml

For more read here:

[colors.xml not generating the correct values in gen/R file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557989/colors-xml-not-generating-the-correct-values-in-gen-r-file)

Hope it helps, cheers.